# Paginating blog posts from SQL server using nested LINQ statements

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I made an ASP.NET MVC application using Entity Framework for code-first migrations to the SQL Server database. I also use Unity (DI/IoC) for managing the services and repositories.

I made an *overview* page but I'll limit the items on that page to 10, 50 or 100 *(variable named `pagecount`)* items as selected by the user. The rest of the items are on other pages *(variable named `page`)*. The result is something similar to what Code review has:

[image]

Each Blog has a Category. I'll also that the user can see one, more, or all categories *(variable named `categories`)*. This contains a list of integers with the categories that the user will see.

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public class BlogRepo : GenericRepo<Blog>
{
    public List<Blog> GetByPage(int page, List<int> categories, int pagecount)
    {
        return (from b1 in ((from b2 in ((from b3 in dbSet.Include(b3 => b3.Category).Include(b3 => b3.User)
                                          orderby b3.CreationDateStamp ascending
                                          where categories.Contains(b3.CategoryId)
                                          select b3).Take<Blog>(page * pagecount)).Include(b2 => b2.Category).Include(b3 => b3.User) // step one
                             orderby b2.CreationDateStamp descending
                             select b2).Take<Blog>(pagecount)).Include(b1 => b1.Category).Include(b3 => b3.User) // step two
                orderby b1.CreationDateStamp ascending
                select b1).ToList<Blog>(); // step tree
    }
}
```

Here is my way of working:

1. I take the first items calculated by the formula `page * pagecount` sorted in ascending order by `CreationDateStamp` where `categories.Contains(b3.CategoryId)` is true.
2. Form that items I sort it in descending order on the same property, and take the value of `pagecount`.
3. Finally, sort it again (ascending), and call `ToList<Blog>()` to materialize the results.

**Note one:** I'll always include the properties `Category` *(type of `Category`)* and `User` *(type of `ApplicationUser`)*.

**Note two:** the variable `dbSet` comes from a generic repository and is declared as follows:

```
public class GenericRepo<TEntity> : IGenericRepo<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;
    // other basic linq statements for get basic stuff like GetAll, Delete, Insert, SaveChanges and Update
}
```

The code works, but I wondering if I can improve its performance and readability. In other words, can I combine some steps and can I reduce the code to make it shorter or simpler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *linq in linq in linq* statement is written as a one-liner, with a single semicolon:

```
return (from b1 in ((from b2 in ((from b3 in dbSet.Include(b3 => b3.Category).Include(b3 => b3.User)
                                  orderby b3.CreationDateStamp ascending
                                  where categories.Contains(b3.CategoryId)
                                  select b3).Take<Blog>(page * pagecount)).Include(b2 => b2.Category).Include(b3 => b3.User) // step one
                     orderby b2.CreationDateStamp descending
                     select b2).Take<Blog>(pagecount)).Include(b1 => b1.Category).Include(b3 => b3.User) // step two
        orderby b1.CreationDateStamp ascending
        select b1).ToList<Blog>(); // step tree
```

In other words, it's *doing too many things* - you even have comments to identify the steps!

LINQ queries don't execute until they're materialized - you can take advantage of that and split the complex query into smaller steps that don't iterate the results.

Step one, *grab all items up to the end of the desired page* - this could be in its own method:

```
private IEnumerable<Blog> FetchItemsUpToSpecifiedPage(int page, int pageSize, IEnumerable<int> categories)
{
    return (from blog in dbSet.Include(item => blog.Category)
                              .Include(item => blog.User)
            orderby blog.CreationDateStamp ascending
            where categories.Contains(blog.CategoryId)
            select blog)
           .Take(page * pageSize);
}
```

Notice the following:

- `pagecount` is renamed to a more accurate `pageSize`; "page count" sounds like like the *number of pages*, but what you want it to convey is the *number of items on a page*.
- Meaningful identifiers. `blog` makes for easier reading than `b3`.
- The compiler infers the generic type argument of `Take<T>` from the `source` parameter of the extension method, so specifying it is redundant and clutters up the code.

Step two, *filter for specified page* - again, in its own method:

```
private IEnumerable<Blog> FilterForSpecifiedPage(int page, int pageSize, IEnumerable<int> categories)
{
    var items = FetchItemsUpToSpecifiedPage(page, pageSize, categories);
    return (from blog in items.Include(item => blog.Category)
                              .Include(item => blog.User)
            orderby blog.CreationDateStamp descending
            select blog)
           .Take(pageSize);
}
```

Step three, *sort and select* - at that point that can go inside `GetByPage`:

```
public IEnumerable<Blog> GetByPage(int page, int pageSize, IEnumerable<int> categories)
{
    var items = FilterForSpecifiedPage(page, pageSize, categories);
    return (from blog in items.Include(item => blog.Category)
                              .Include(item => blog.User)
            orderby blog.CreationDateStamp ascending
            select blog)
           .ToList();
}
```

Now, this is *strictly equivalent* and improves nothing but readability, by un-nesting the queries.

I believe the `.Include` calls are redundant anywhere other than in the final step, in `GetByPage` - by *including* them so deep in the query you're carrying more data than you actually need along the way; I'd try removing them in the two private methods, and see if I get the same results.

Notice I'm returning an `IEnumerable<Blog>` and not a `List<Blog>` - the client code shouldn't be *adding* or *removing* items from this result set, and so doesn't need a `List<Blog>`. Rather, it merely needs to *enumerate* the results, so `IEnumerable<Blog>` is enough for its needs. And it's an interface, so you're not tying your hands with a specific implementation either.

---

Your pagination seems rather inefficient, you're sorting back and forth and back again.

Instead of sorting backwards and `Take`ing, you could look into what `Skip` can do for you - I believe it could boil down to something like this (untested):

```
return (from blog in dbSet.Include(item => item.Category)
                          .Include(item => item.User)
        where categories.Contains(blog.CategoryId)
        order by blog.CreationDate)
       .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
       .Take(pageSize)
       .ToList();
```

...which basically means, scratch pretty much everything I said above about extracting to private methods :)

Comment: The reason why I used `b3` is because b is the first leter and the number indicate is the step. Thanks a lot to give better code.  :)